# How to create multiple subfolders?

Tags: powershell

How do I create a folder structure where I have one root folder, then approximately 9 differently named subfolders; within these subfolders there another set of differently named subfolders.  I have already made one .csv file with the script.  But I do not feel like writing out 30 lines of the same code to make these subfolders.

Here is what I have so far:

```psh
$LogsDir = "D:\Logs"

If (-Not (Test-Path $LogsDir)) {
    New-Item -Path $LogsDir -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
} Else {
    Write-Host "Directory already exists!"
}

$Subfolders1 = Import-Csv "Subfolders1.csv";

$Subfolders1 | Where-Object {$_.Type -eq 'Subfolder'} |
    ForEach-Object {
        $Subfolders1 = $_.Name;
        New-Item "$LogsDir\$Subfolders1" -ItemType Directory
    }

# ******sbf1 = the first set of subfolders******
# ******sf-** = the second set******

New-Item -Path "$LogsDir\sbf1\sf-a1" -ItemType Directory
New-Item -Path "$LogsDir\sbf1\sf-a2" -ItemType Directory
New-Item -Path "$LogsDir\sbf1\sf-a3" -ItemType Directory
New-Item -Path "$LogsDir\sbf2\sf-a1" -ItemType Directory
New-Item -Path "$LogsDir\sbf2\sf-a2" -ItemType Directory
New-Item -Path "$LogsDir\sbf2\sf-b2" -ItemType Directory
```

I am trying to create a log file folder tree.  I think I got some of it down but any help would appreciated.

Comment: did you try to put the creation step in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

[`New-Item`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849795.aspx) will create missing parent folders, so you only need a list of the leaf folders (with full path):

```
D:\Logs\sbf1\sf-a1
D:\Logs\sbf1\sf-a2
D:\Logs\sbf1\sf-a3
D:\Logs\sbf2\sf-a1
D:\Logs\sbf2\sf-a2
D:\Logs\sbf2\sf-b2
```

and then create the folders like this:

```psh
Get-Content 'C:\path\to\subfolders.txt' | % {
  New-Item -Type Directory -Path $_
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Trying to get back to it.